# Address family not supported by protocol family

Tags: ruby, unicorn

I tried to do the ruby example shown in this page: http://tomayko.com/writings/unicorn-is-unix

but all I got was

```
echo.rb:9:in `bind': Address family not supported by protocol family - bind(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)
    from echo.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem. Just change the `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`:

```
address = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(4242, '0.0.0.0')
```

It seems to appear on Mac only.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use domain names in this method, you must use IP addresses:

- 127.0.0.1 for localhost
- 0.0.0.0 for *all* interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check in at http://rubyforge.org/mailman/listinfo/mongrel-unicorn and ask there.